# Limescale formation at room temperature?

Tags: water

There is a large metal container in form of a cube made of stainless steel. It is used for storing water in it for technical uses. The problem is that all joints at the bottom of the container have micro cavities and water leaks through them very slowly. I am thinking of a method to close these micro cavities from inside. And the most reasonable method I can think of is to make them cover by a layer of limescale, as any electrical teapot or heater does. The only problem is that this is a big container, and it isn't easy to heat that amount of water, or to boil it.

So does anybody know any other way to cover the bottom or just micro cavities in the joints by limescale without heating during long time? Maybe some use of electrolysis?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [solution of a suitable polymer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sealant). As the solution leaks it will dry in the outside air, solidify and block the holes. You might try [Radweld](http://www.holtsauto.com/products/group/repair-and-maintenance/cooling-repair-systems#holts-radweld).

Comment: That may be a good idea, but I am looking for something that can be made by yourself.

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you mean by "something that can be made by yourself". Assuming you're anywhere near civilisation you can nip down the road and buy Radweld. If you're stuck in the wilderness tap some latex from a rubber tree and use that.

Comment: I live in Ukraine and I'm sure that there is no Radweld for sell in Ukraine. And I don't know about other sealants that are liquid but solidify after contact with the air. So I am asking about some physical or chemical process that can create the needed effect.

Comment: Every country that uses cars has someone selling car radiator sealant - Radweld is just the brand name in the UK and you'll have similar products sold under different names. You could always try asking your local mechanic what they use to seal car radiators. If you really can't find any you could try latex wood glue (the white glue) diluted into the water.